# Sparklyr with another R package?

Tags: r, apache-spark, package, sparklyr

I work with an R package *rehh*. Can I use **sparklyr** to run within *rehh* functions? Is that possble?

I am adding a link to my another question, related to what I am trying to do in rehh and the problem encountered with it :  [R error in scan!! Too many items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578840/r-error-in-scan-too-many-items)

I thought using sparklyr would resolve the problem encountered while using large amount of datasets.

Answer (score 1):

If whatever `rehh` package does could be done in parallel - you can use [`spark_apply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/spark_apply) function.

Comment: Please see the updated question. Thanks :)