# R error in scan!! Too many items

Tags: r, package

I am working with *rehh* package of R.

I have to create an object of class haplohh from the function *data2haplohh*:

```
test<-data2haplohh(hap_file="test.hap", map_file="test.map.inp", haplotype.in.columns=TRUE)
Map file seems OK: 1054416  SNPs declared for chromosome 1

Haplotype are in columns with no header

Error in scan(hap_file, what = "character", quiet = TRUE) :
  too many items
```

So the *.hap file has 1054416 lines and 5008 columns(approx 10 GB size), *.map.inp file has 1054416 lines and  5 columns(15 MB size).
My systems working RAM memory is 64 GB and 8TB is the storage space

I have an option of chopping up the files but, in this case It would create errors in my calculation. So I need to load the input files as a whole.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://www.biostars.org/p/317671/